# Is it possible to deploy a SharePoint WSP without causing an IIS Reset?

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2010, deployment, wsp

I'm working in SharePoint 2010 and have been unable to deploy (or retract) my WSP without causing an IISReset. Here's my situation:

•The solution contains:

•Fields
  •One content type
  •A page layout based on the content type
  •A bunch of images that go into the style library

•There is ZERO code in the solution

•I've manually edited the manifest.xml

•Removed the assembly, so nothing would get deployed to the GAC
•Set ResetWebServer="False" in the Solution tag

Still, every retract or deploy takes down ALL web applications on the server. Is there any way even to restrict it just to one web app? Thanks!

edit:  additional info - I'm packaging up the WSP and deploying with powershell commands, but I get the same behavior even if I deploy through Central Admin.

Comment: I had thought `ResetWebServer="FALSE"` was the ticket. This makes me check my assumptions.

Comment: I use WSPBuilder and, from the same machine (possibly remotely with some work), you can just perform a copy to the GAC/80-HIVE. Using a "simple copy" may or may not make your dev. more productive (you should always test against a clean deploy though). Of course this falls flat in a real farm environment ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for a high-traffic public-facing site, and my solution must go through multiple rounds of testing and deployment.  Thus, it must be a WSP.  But the business has requested zero downtime for this update, and is willing to pay for my time to figure out how.  For a less high-profile site, I would just schedule deployment for midnight and be done.

Answer (score 0):

try this in SP Admin console (with credential admin):

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename "C:\yourwsp.wsp"

stsadm -o deploysolution -name yourwsp.wsp -url http://yourspsite -allowgacdeployment –immediate

stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```